# Issues converting HTML slides to pdf using slidify

Tags: r, pdf, slidify

Here is the first part of the resport:
The code is done in Rmd, and i`m using slidify to create HTML slides in order to convert them to pdf. More details below the code.

````
---
title       : Planes Control
subtitle    : Gerencia de Inteligencia Comercial
author      : Analytics
job         : Martin Azcona
framework   : io2012        # {io2012, html5slides, shower, dzslides, ...}
highlighter : highlight  # {highlight.js, prettify, highlight}
hitheme     : tomorrow      # 
widgets     : []            # {mathjax, quiz, bootstrap}
mode        : selfcontained # {standalone, draft}
---

## Analisis del Trafico
## Planes Control & Comunidad
### Gerencia de Inteligencia Comercial
### Analytics
### Martin Azcona

--- .class #id

## Objetivos & Metodologia
### Describir el consumo de los clientes Prepago
### Comparar el consumo con la distribucion de los clusters comportamentales
### Transmitir la informacion graficamente

--- .class #id

## Estructura del Informe
### Analisis del Consumo: Minutos, SMS, Datos abierto por plan
### Se utilizara la facturacion total para tener en cuenta a que oferta 2014 esta asociada cada cliente
### Comparacion del Consumo entre Segmentacion comportamental y rangos de facturacion

--- .class #id

## Frecuencia de rangos de facturacion de clientes Control

```{r , fig.width = 14, fig.height = 6, fig.align = 'center', message = F, echo =FALSE}
#invisible(sapply(pkg, require, c=T))
setwd("C://Users//mazcona//Desktop//APC")
source("1_prep.R")
source("ggfreq.R")
ggfrq(agg(DT,PLAN))
```

La idea del analisis es tomar rangos de facturacion similares a las nuevas ofertas control.

--- .class #id

## Frecuencia de Clusters Comportamentales de clientes Control

```{r , fig.width = 14, fig.height = 6, fig.align = 'center', message = F, echo =FALSE}
frq_cl <- agg(DT, DESC_CLUSTER)[percentage > 0]
frq_cl <- frq_cl[x %in% clusters]
frq_cl$x <- factor(frq_cl$x, levels = clusters)
ggfrq(frq_cl)
```

Los clusters mas importantes en control son: Free, Retro y Timidos
````

The problem is the slides division is messep up when i convert it to pdf. 
So the title of one slide appears on the end of the next one. 
However, the slides look great in HTML5.
I´m using chrome's "printing method" to convert the slides to pdf. I`ve been using this in the past, and had no problem with previous versions of slidify. 
**So, how can i convert the HTML5 slides "successfully" to pdf?**

I don`t have enought reputation to post images, sorry. (If upvoted once, i will.)

Comment: I believe it is due to some updates in Chrome. It might need some CSS level fixes. Can you file an issue on the github repo? An issue was filed on the google io2012 slides repo https://code.google.com/p/io-2012-slides/issues/detail?id=30.

Comment: If this approach doesn`t work, is there another "converter" i should use? I`ll file the issue, thx for your answer.

Comment: I believe pdf printing works correctly from firefox and safari.

Comment: yeah. That worked just ok! thanks Ramnath for the assistance!

Comment: Should I post as answer so that you can close this question?

Comment: I found that, currently, a workaround is to print with Firefox, by setting the advanced options to landscape and omitting header/footer/background. Must be done one document at a time and 'manually', so basically it's a pain.